# Spark and Hive interoperability

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, hive, parquet

I am using EMR-4.3.0, Spark 1.6.0, Hive 1.0.0.

I write a table like so (pseudocode) -

```
val df = <a dataframe>
df.registerTempTable("temptable")
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode","true")
sqlContext.sql("create external table exttable ( some columns ... )
partitioned by (partkey int) stored as parquet location 's3://some.bucket'")
sqlContext.sql("insert overwrite exttable partition(partkey) select columns from 
temptable")
```

The write works fine and I can read the table back using -

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from exttable")
```

However, when I try to read the table using Hive as -

```
hive -e 'select * from exttable'
```

Hive throws a NullPointerException with the stack trace below. Any help appreciated! -

```
questTime=[0.008], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.295], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.313],
2016-05-19 03:08:02,537 ERROR [main()]: CliDriver (SessionState.java:printError(833)) - Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:663)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:570)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:247)
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:368)
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:346)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:296)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.getSplit(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:588)
        ... 15 more
```

**UPDATE** - After messing around for a bit, it seems like null values in the data mess Hive up. How do I avoid this?

Comment: I am facing the exact problem. Has anyone found a workaround/solution ?